# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Tags: php, css, html

I'm fairly new at this, so please excuse my ignorance.

I'm trying to order my posts in the site's categories with a button, 'ascending' / 'descending'.

I'm trying to use 'sortit' function because that's the only source I could find online; been working on this all the past week.

So what I did here is;

```
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Sırala</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="?sortby=asc" class="nav-link dropdown-item" type="button" role="tab">Yeniden Eskiye</a></li>
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="?sortby=desc" class="nav-link dropdown-item" type="button" role="tab">Eskiden Yeniye</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        </li>
```

Add a code to the menu, so the URL will be '?sortby=asc' or '?sortby=desc'

(Web site is in Turkish so ignore the texts)

The next step was adding a function.

```
    function sortIt($sortType)
    {
    global $wp_query;
    $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');

    if (strcmp($sortType, 'ASC') )
    {
        $newQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'orderby' => 'date' ,
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'cat' => $cat_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => '10') );
    }

    if (strcmp($sortType, 'DESC') )
    {
        $newQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'orderby' => 'date' ,
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $cat_ID,
        'posts_per_page' => '10') );
    }

    return $newQuery;
    }
```

Next step is displaying them when the button is clicked, but it will crash into each other with the current order so and if-else must be created here. What I did is

```
<?php if (is_page('echo esc_url( wp_get_current_url()/?sortby=asc')) {
                          if ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : $newQuery->the_post();
                          } else { if (is_page('echo esc_url( wp_get_current_url()/?sortby=desc')) {
                          if ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : $newQuery->the_post();
                          } } else { if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                          } ?>
```

But now I'm getting an error, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in"

Any ideas? Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: First check your use of is_page() function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Second, I guess, you do not need 'echo' function within string.

Comment: `<?php if (is_page(array('/?sortby=asc', '/?sortby=desc'))) { ?>` how about this?

Comment: No, that is query argument, is_page() requires page ID or slug or title. 

I guess, you will have to change a lot here.

I recommend to start reading here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

or here: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/reorder-wordpress-posts-using-drag-drop/#code

Sorry, I can't help you more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that last block, there's a mix of bracketed and bracket-free if statements that make it hard to debug. I'd suggest rewriting it like this and using indentation to make it easier to see what is going on at a glance:

```
if (is_page(esc_url( wp_get_current_url() . '/?sortby=asc'))) {
    if ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) { 
        while ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) {
            $newQuery->the_post();
        }   
    }
} else { 
    if (is_page(esc_url( wp_get_current_url() . '/?sortby=desc'))) {
        if ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $newQuery->have_posts() ) {
                $newQuery->the_post();
            }
        }
    } else { 
        if (have_posts()) {
            while (have_posts()) {
                the_post();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An editor with syntax highlighting, like VSCode for example, also makes this a lot easier — it changes pairs of bracket colors so that they match.

There are some other problems in the code, though:

- As @ddur mentioned `is_page()` is also used incorrectly, you can [see this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/409821/335) for more details (which you've already seen).
- You could use `else if` to simplify these nested `if` statements quite a lot and make it easier to read
- Those echo statements don't work the way you think, see the code above instead

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is a standard PHP error that results from the fact that you're not matching the order and pairing of curly braces (`{` and `}`) in your code... ...PHP is expecting one thing, but finding another.

Also, you're breaking things by the way you're using the `echo`, you shouldn't be echoing anything inside of `is_page()`.

I don't know if this code will work, but here it is properly formatted:

```
if( is_page( esc_url( wp_get_current_url() . '/?sortby=asc' ) ) ) :
    if( $newQuery->have_posts() ) :
        while( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : $newQuery->the_post();
    endif;
elseif( is_page( esc_url( wp_get_current_url() . '/?sortby=asc' ) ) ) :
    if( $newQuery->have_posts() ) :
        while( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : $newQuery->the_post();
    endif;
else :
    if( have_posts() ) :
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    endif;
endif;
```

Try to stick to a coding pattern, like using:

```
if() :
  //do a thing
endif;
```

Or...

```
if() {
  //do a thing
}
```

Mixing between the two makes it hard for you to keep track of what's what.

`wp_get_current_url()` isn't an actual WP function, so I don't know where that comes from or what it outputs.

I think your best bet is to check if the parameter matches `sortby` and if it does then run you alternative queries.

```
if( isset( $_GET['sortby'] ) ) :
  if( $newQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while( $newQuery->have_posts() ) : $newQuery->the_post();
  endif;
else :
  if( have_posts() ) :
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  endif;
endif;
```

Again, I don't know if any of this will work.  I don't know what `$newQuery` is or how it's built, I don't know where you got `wp_get_current_url()`...